# Дух сообщества назначил конкурс, и баллы сгорели?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Забавная ситуация. Был объявлен конкурс по вопросу [*Правильное использование проверки конца файла*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342). По истечении конкурса баллы не были назначены ни одному из двух ответов и сгорели. Назначал конкурс т.н. "*Дух сообщества*" :)

Так вот, просто интересно - что это было? Какой был смысл в выбрасывании баллов на ветер?

Comment: я думаю участник начал конкурс и удалил свой аккаунт

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как уже предположил в комментарии Danis, подобная ситуация возникает при удалении учётной записи пользователя, начавшего конкурс. Об этом написано на MSE: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/339911)

> #### What happens if I delete my account while I have an active bounty?
>
> The bounty will just be moved to (owned) by [the Community
> user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
> and will be awarded automatically at the end of the period as they
> normally would.
> ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89614/152859))

Свободный перевод: вознаграждение просто перемещается (во владение) к Духу сообщества и будет автоматически вручено в конце конкурса как обычно происходит с конкурсами.

Для автоматического вручение награды ответу требуется **одновременное** выполнение трёх условий:

1. Ответ опубликован после начала конкурса
2. Ответ имеет рейтинг 2 и более (на момент автоматического награждения)
3. Конкурс предложен не автором ответа

Т.к. первый пункт не выполнен ни для одного из ответов (оба ответа опубликованы в 2018 году), то награда вручена не была.

Comment: Откуда третий пункт взялся?

Comment: @Qwertiy из ответа на MSE. Всё доступно по ссылке.

Comment: @Qwertiy кэшбэка в баунти нет ;)